# Batch retrieval of friend profile photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, profile, photos

I have successfully retrieved up to 50 user's profiles using the batching method.  I attempted to use the same process to retrieve these user's profile photos, but get an error 302. I see that there is a URL pointing to the photo returned in the result, but using that to retrieve each photo would defeat the purpose of batching, which is to retrieve all at once and prevent repeated HTTP requests.  Is it possible to retrieve these using the batching in the Facebook API?

Answer (score 0):

Try FQL:

```
SELECT pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

...where `pic_square` can be one of `pic_small`, `pic_big`, `pic_square`, `pic`

That'll give you URLs for the corresponding user's profile picture at the given size.

e.g.:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20pic_square%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29